# Using nested For Loop in Bash with IF statement

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, nested

I have a directory containing a number of .cntl files - I am using a For Loop to delete all the files however I want to keep 2 of the .cntl files. This is a basic version on what I have so far

```
MY_DIR=/home/shell/

CNTL_FILE_LIST=`find ${MY_DIR}*.cntl -type f`

CNTL_EXCEPTION_LIST="/home/shell/test4.cntl /home/shell/test5.cntl"
```

I am having some syntax issues with my below nested For Loop. I am trying to delete all cntl files in MY_DIR except test4.cntl and test5.cntl

```
for file in CNTL_FILE_LIST
do
  for exception in CNTL_EXCEPTION_LIST
  do
    if [ "${file}" != ${exception} ]
       rm $file
    fi
  done
done
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Putting `set -x` (which makes the shell print commands as it executes them) may make it easier to see what's going wrong.

Comment: @GaryM : It really does not make sense if you complain about "having some syntax issues", if you not also post the error message and indicate the line where the error occurs.

Answer (score 3):

In practice, you should **let `find` itself do the work of excluding files, as described in the second part (using `-not`) of [the answer by user unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49375082/14122)**. That said, to demonstrate how one might safely use bash for this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case $BASH_VERSION in
  ''|[1-3].*) echo "ERROR: Bash 4.0 or newer required" >&2; exit 1;;
esac

# Use of lowercase names here is deliberate -- POSIX specifies all-caps names for variables
# ...meaningful to the operating system or shell; other names are available for application
# ...use; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html,
# fourth paragraph.
my_dir=/home/shell

# Using an associative array rather than a regular one allows O(1) lookup
declare -A cntl_exception_list
cntl_exception_list=(
  ["${my_dir}/test4.cntl"]=1
  ["${my_dir}/test5.cntl"]=1
)

while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
  [[ ${cntl_exception_list[$file]} ]] && continue
  rm -f -- "$file"
done < <(find "$my_dir" -type f -print0)
```

---

Note:

- `declare -A` creates an associative array. These can have arbitrary strings as keys; here, we can use our names to match again as such keys.
- Using NUL-delimited filenames (`-print0`) ensures that even names with whitespace or literal newlines are unambiguously represented.
- See [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for the syntax used for the `while read` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Well file4.cntl is != file5.cntl and get's therefore deleted on comparing it, file5.cntl gets deleted when compared to file4.cntl.

```
MY_DIR=/home/shell/
CNTL_FILE_LIST=`find ${MY_DIR}*.cntl -type f`
CNTL_EXCEPTION_LIST="/home/shell/test4.cntl /home/shell/test5.cntl"

for file in CNTL_FILE_LIST
do
  for exception in CNTL_EXCEPTION_LIST
  do
    if [ "${file}" != ${exception} ]
       rm $file
    fi
  done
done
```

Instead use just find:

```
find ${MY_DIR} -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.cntl" -not -name "file4.cntl" -not -name "file5.cntl"  -delete
```

But not every find supports -delete, Gnu-find does, and you have to know, if -maxdepth 1 applies for you.

Try first with -ls instead of -delete.

Comment: And for files that are not either test4.cntl nor test5.cntl, it'll try to delete them twice (once because they aren't test4.cntl, and then again because they aren't test5.cntl).

Comment: (...which is to say, second half of this is perfect, first half is unfortunate insofar as it's reiterating code known to be broken, and a lot of readers here tend to copy-and-paste the code and ignore the surrounding prose).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Your comment is just ridiculous. I cite the broken code to explain why it fails. To expect people ignoring the prose around it and copying it blindly is just ... - I don't know how to say it friendly, it looks a bit paranoid as if you expect all the users are idiots and you're obliged to nanny around them. You might handle your own answers in this fashion but please stay away with that habit from my postings.

Answer (score 0):

[user unknow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49375082/7714132) is right. So you should probably not doing this.

**Instead, you can remove `$CNTL_EXCEPTION_LIST` from `$CNTL_FILE_LIST` before doing the deletion.**

```
for i in $CNTL_EXCEPTION_LIST
do
        CNTL_FILE_LIST=${CNTL_FILE_LIST//$i/}
done
```

You can reference to `man bash` for this usage, just search `Pattern  substitution`.

After this, $CNTL_FILE_LIST will NOT inclued the exceptions anymore, and now you can safely delete them by `rm $CNTL_FILE_LIST`.

Comment: `for i in $anything` is innately buggy. Content to be iterated over should be stored in an array, whereafter one can iterate with `for i in "${anything[@]}"` -- or `for idx in "${!anything[@]}"; do i=${anything[$idx]}; unset "anything[$idx]"; ...; done` if one really wants to remove things.

Comment: `${CNTL_FILE_LIST//$i/}` will alter any reference to `file10` when you finish iterating over `file1`; it's innately broken. And a filename with spaces stored in the string will have each piece (split on such spaces) treated as a completely separate name.

Comment: Those are very good points, thanks for that. And I forget the double quotes. Let me try to make it robust.